# Odoo Custom filter function

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I already tried everything and searched everywhere for an answer but I wasn't successful.

I want to implement a custom function to retrieve filtered values for a Many2one selection list.
Usually you would use a domain for that but the domain-options given are not sufficient to achieve my goal.

What function do I have to override to modify the selection list for a given Many2one field?

Thank you,
Lars

**UPDATE:**

Thank you for your answers. I used `name_search` to analyze the generated WHERE clause.
Here what I want to achieve and my findings so far:

```
programs = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='hr.program',
        relation='hr_process_onboarding_wizard_programs')
program_department = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='hr.department',
        domain="[('programs', 'in', programs)]")
```

Field *programs* is represented as a many2many_checkboxes widget.
When I select 2 values, the following domain-filter is being passed to `name_search`: `['programs', 'in', [1, 2]]`

This will generate the following SQL-Query (excerpt of the interesting part): `(SELECT "hr_department_id" FROM "hr_programs_departments" WHERE "hr_program_id" IN (1,2))`

The result list is of course the UNION of programs [1,2] but I would expect the INTERSECTION of programs [1,2].

Afaik there is no domain filter to get the intersection.

**UPDATE 2:**

After thinking about the given filter operators I would expect `=` to do exactly what I want but operator `=` is generating the same WHERE clause as for `in`.

Comment: Please provide a sample of input data and a desired output

Comment: first guess: override `name_search()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my quick-hack solution using `name_search` in class `HrDepartment`.

I added a attribute `context="{'intersect': True}"` to the field in the corresponding view to be failsafe in other contexts.

The `domain` is still in place and being used in `must_contain_programs`.

```py
@api.model
def name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    is_intersect_context = self._context.get('intersect')
    must_contain_programs = args[0][2]
    if(is_intersect_context and len(must_contain_programs) > 1):
        all_departments = self.env['hr.department'].search([])
        filtered_departments = []
        for department in all_departments:
            if all(program_id in department.programs.ids for program_id in must_contain_programs):
                filtered_departments.append(department)
        if len(filtered_departments) > 0:
            intersect_res = []
            for filtered_department in filtered_departments:
                intersect_res.append((filtered_department.id, filtered_department.name))
            intersect_res.sort(key=lambda tuple: tuple[0])
            if name != '':
                res = list(filter(lambda tuple: name.upper() in tuple[1].upper(), intersect_res))
            else:
                res = intersect_res
    else:
        res = super(HrDepartment, self).name_search(name, args, operator, limit)
    return res
```

Comment: Is it possible to override the apply method of custom add filter? I want to have the parameters of custom add filter and for specific field I want to filter more and return.

Answer (score 0):

I think we are on the same page, I would like to sugest the **_search** method because everytime when you hit on the many2one field this **_search** method with your written domain in py or xml.

You can override it and do useful.

One thing you need to be aware whenever you are overriding such methods.
I'll suggest you to pass context from your field and one condition inside the _search method (on top of all code) so your code will be not affected to other places, because **_search** method used everywhere.

Thanks

Comment: `_search` is not applicable here, because `program_department` is not a calculated field.

Comment: I think the name_search method that you have suggested is indirectly called the _search method so the same concept we'll apply on search method also.